# Creating condition for mosaicing images in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, mosaic, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, conditional

I am trying to create a mosaic of a several classified images using as criteria that every pixel has to be the same class at least for three images.

A similar process can be done using the `.min()` or `.max()` functions, that will return the pixel corresponding either to the min or max value. Example:

```
// Collection of classified images
var collection = ee.ImageCollection([image1, image2, image3, image4])

// Function to select a specific class
var selectClass = function(img) {
    var select = img.eq(2); //Select class 2
    var maskImg = img.mask(select); //Mask other classes and let only class 2
    return maskImg.unmask(0) //Assign a no data value to masked pixels
}

// Create new collection with only class 2
var collectionNew = collection.map(selectClass)

// Create mosaic using .min(). If there is at least one stacked pixel with the value 0, 
// then it will return this instead of class 2. 
var mosaic = collectionNew.min()
```

Now, what I want is to create a mosaic with the condition of returning the pixel value of class 2 if there is three or more pixels with the same value, otherwise return 0.

Is this possible in GEE using the JavaScript API?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about how to do this using the Python API then please do that in a separate question that includes a Python code attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I want to post the solution I found for this, using just math logics. If someone has a better suggestion please post it.

```
// Sum all the pixels, in this case this collection only has pixel values equal
// to 2 and 0
var sumCollection = collectionNew.sum();

// So, I'm interested on keeping only the pixels of class 2 that are present at
// least three times in the stack of images. In this example I have a stack of 4
// images, so the new pixel values according to their presence in the images is:

// Class 2 presence:
// *In 4 images: pixel value = 8
// *In 3 images: pixel value = 6
// *In 2 images: pixel values = 4
// *In 1 image: pixel value = 2
// *Any image: pixel value = 0
```

With this, I can filter the pixel values again using `.gt(6)` and then use it as a mask.

```
var condition = sumCollection.gt(6)
var finalCollection = sumCollection.updateMask(condition)
```

This was my solution. Kind of tricky.